# how to code to count number of repeatation of dates by using pandas.series.map?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

This code can count the frequency of dates in this way : Monday, Tuesday,Wednesday and Thursday together and Saturday,Sunday together.
How to change the arguments of map function to get repeatation of dates in two groups: 
1. 9 am to 5pm weekdays 
2. the rest of hours in the week (5pm to 9am weekdays and weekends).

```
d = ['10/3/2013 18:36', '10/3/2013 23:40', '10/3/2013 20:56', '10/4/2013 9:35', '11/7/2013 10:02', '11/11/2013 14:45', '12/1/2013 12:04']
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(d), columns=["DATE"])

df["DATE"].dt.weekday.map({0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:1,6:1}).value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `.map()` can be applied directly on the Series and also takes an arbitrary function, you can use:

```
df['DATE'].map(lambda dt:
    'Office' if dt.weekday() in {0,1,2,3,4} and 9 <= dt.hour < 17
    else 'Out of office'
).value_counts()
```

The result is:

```
Out of office    4
Office           3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Comparing the hour with `<= 17` will count times from 5:00-5:59pm as in office hours, I think you want `< 17`.

Comment: Thanks @Marius -- you're absolutely right. Thanks for correcting this.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has some built-in methods for identifying business days. There might actually be some built-in functions for business hours but I'm not sure as I don't deal with datetimes that often:

```
df['in_business_hours'] = (
    df['DATE'].map(pd.datetools.isBusinessDay) & 
    ((9 <= df.DATE.dt.hour) & (df.DATE.dt.hour <= 16))
)
df['in_business_hours'].value_counts()
Out[14]: 
False    4
True     3
dtype: int64
```